# Confusing OCaml Base/Core library deprecation warnings

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-core

I've been trying Jane Street's Base / Core libraries for a few hours now, and I got very confused by depracation warnings.

With the following code:

```ml
open Base
(* open Core *)
open Stdio

let _ = printf "%d" (4 mod 3)
```

I get a deprecation warning:

```sh
Alert deprecated: Base.mod
[2016-09] this element comes from the stdlib distributed with OCaml.
Use (%), which has slightly different semantics, or Int.rem which is equivalent.
```

I get that I have to use `%` or `Int.rem`, but when I simply `open Core`, the warning disappears.
The documentation doesn't seem to clarify much regarding these 'deprecations'.

Also, with the following code:

```ml
(* open Base *)
open Core
(* open Stdio *)

let _ = Out_channel.output_string stdout "Hello, OCaml"
let line = In_channel.input_line_exn stdin
```

I get

```sh
Alert deprecated: Core.stdin
[since 2016-04] Use [In_channel.stdin]
```

but surprisingly, no alert for `stdout`.

When I uncomment the `(* open Stdio *)` line, I no longer get warnings.
I can guess that Stdio module is probably shadowing the stdin/stdout, but I thought `open Core` was enough for this as it depends on the Stdio module.

I used

```sh
ocamlfind ocamlopt -o output.out -linkpkg -package base,stdio -thread output.ml
```

and with `-package base,stdio`, respectively.

1. Why am I not getting a deprecation warning for 'mod' when I use `open Core`, if it warned me if I used `open Base`?
2. Why am I getting no alert for `stdout`?

2-1. Is it normal necessary to `open Stdio` as well when I `open Core`?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @glennsl Sorry if the question was unclear. I updated the post for clarification.